# Bluetooth disappears from time to time. RTL8821CE, kernel 5.10.0-1057-oem, Ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

Bluetooth disappears from time to time. Adapter RTL8821CE (Wireless LAN + bluetooth). Wifi works normally. Kernel 5.10.0-1057-oem. Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. I use kernel driver. Alternative driver is off.

Comment: I have updated bios today. Bluetooth is still not detected in bios. I have also tried dkms driver rtl8821ce - no bluetooth, and I have returned to kernel driver rtw_8821ce.

Comment: Bluetooth works again after update of xorg-video package in Ubuntu 22.04. It is seen in bios as well.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth works normally on 22.04 Jammy. I think it is due to new linux-firmware package.